# FEDEX shipment rate details missing in Shipping Label generation for Third party payment

Tags: java, web-services, soap, fedex

I am using FEDEX API to get shipping labels from FEDEX using their ShipService WSDL. I have integrated the functionality in my appication and successfully able to generate labels from FEDEX.

Due to a recent requirement, we needed to add **ThirdParty as a payor** option from our application. To implement this, i changed **PaymentType from SENDER to THIRD_PARTY** and also populated necessary fields like address, contact etc as per FEDEX API documentation.

```
payment.setPaymentType(PaymentType.THIRD_PARTY);
```

The service call is successful and i am getting valid response as well but the ShipmentRate details are missing when using THIRD_PARTY as Payor which was available when using SENDER as PaymentType. I require the Rate details for further processing in my application.

Below are the details which i get with SENDER PaymentType.

```
<v13:CompletedShipmentDetail>
    <v13:ShipmentRating>
        <v13:ActualRateType>PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE</v13:ActualRateType>
        <v13:ShipmentRateDetails>
            <v13:RateType>PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE</v13:RateType>
            <v13:RateZone>4</v13:RateZone>
            <v13:RatedWeightMethod>DIM</v13:RatedWeightMethod>
            <v13:DimDivisor>166</v13:DimDivisor>
            <v13:FuelSurchargePercent>4.25</v13:FuelSurchargePercent>
            <v13:TotalBillingWeight>
                <v13:Units>LB</v13:Units>
                <v13:Value>17.0</v13:Value>
            </v13:TotalBillingWeight>
            <v13:TotalDimWeight>
                <v13:Units>LB</v13:Units>
                <v13:Value>17.0</v13:Value>
            </v13:TotalDimWeight>
            <v13:TotalBaseCharge>
                <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                <v13:Amount>11.32</v13:Amount>
            </v13:TotalBaseCharge>
            <v13:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                <v13:Amount>0.0</v13:Amount>
            </v13:TotalFreightDiscounts>
            <v13:TotalNetFreight>
                <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                <v13:Amount>11.32</v13:Amount>
            </v13:TotalNetFreight>
            <v13:TotalSurcharges>
                <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                <v13:Amount>9.48</v13:Amount>
            </v13:TotalSurcharges>
            <v13:TotalNetFedExCharge>
                <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                <v13:Amount>20.8</v13:Amount>
            </v13:TotalNetFedExCharge>
            <v13:TotalTaxes>
                <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                <v13:Amount>0.0</v13:Amount>
            </v13:TotalTaxes>
            <v13:TotalNetCharge>
                <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                <v13:Amount>20.8</v13:Amount>
            </v13:TotalNetCharge>
            <v13:TotalRebates>
                <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                <v13:Amount>0.0</v13:Amount>
            </v13:TotalRebates>
            <v13:Surcharges>
                <v13:SurchargeType>ADDITIONAL_HANDLING</v13:SurchargeType>
                <v13:Level>PACKAGE</v13:Level>
                <v13:Description>Additional handling surcharge - dimension</v13:Description>
                <v13:Amount>
                    <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                    <v13:Amount>9.0</v13:Amount>
                </v13:Amount>
            </v13:Surcharges>
            <v13:Surcharges>
                <v13:SurchargeType>FUEL</v13:SurchargeType>
                <v13:Level>PACKAGE</v13:Level>
                <v13:Description>FedEx Ground Fuel</v13:Description>
                <v13:Amount>
                    <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                    <v13:Amount>0.48</v13:Amount>
                </v13:Amount>
            </v13:Surcharges>
        </v13:ShipmentRateDetails>
    </v13:ShipmentRating>
    <v13:CompletedPackageDetails>
        <v13:SequenceNumber>1</v13:SequenceNumber>
        <v13:TrackingIds>
            <v13:TrackingIdType>FEDEX</v13:TrackingIdType>
            <v13:TrackingNumber>794662859722</v13:TrackingNumber>
        </v13:TrackingIds>
        <v13:GroupNumber>0</v13:GroupNumber>
        <v13:PackageRating>
            <v13:ActualRateType>PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE</v13:ActualRateType>
            <v13:PackageRateDetails>
                <v13:RateType>PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE</v13:RateType>
                <v13:RatedWeightMethod>DIM</v13:RatedWeightMethod>
                <v13:BillingWeight>
                    <v13:Units>LB</v13:Units>
                    <v13:Value>17.0</v13:Value>
                </v13:BillingWeight>
                <v13:DimWeight>
                    <v13:Units>LB</v13:Units>
                    <v13:Value>17.0</v13:Value>
                </v13:DimWeight>
                <v13:BaseCharge>
                    <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                    <v13:Amount>11.32</v13:Amount>
                </v13:BaseCharge>
                <v13:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                    <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                    <v13:Amount>0.0</v13:Amount>
                </v13:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                <v13:NetFreight>
                    <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                    <v13:Amount>11.32</v13:Amount>
                </v13:NetFreight>
                <v13:TotalSurcharges>
                    <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                    <v13:Amount>9.48</v13:Amount>
                </v13:TotalSurcharges>
                <v13:NetFedExCharge>
                    <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                    <v13:Amount>20.8</v13:Amount>
                </v13:NetFedExCharge>
                <v13:TotalTaxes>
                    <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                    <v13:Amount>0.0</v13:Amount>
                </v13:TotalTaxes>
                <v13:NetCharge>
                    <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                    <v13:Amount>20.8</v13:Amount>
                </v13:NetCharge>
                <v13:TotalRebates>
                    <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                    <v13:Amount>0.0</v13:Amount>
                </v13:TotalRebates>
                <v13:Surcharges>
                    <v13:SurchargeType>ADDITIONAL_HANDLING</v13:SurchargeType>
                    <v13:Level>PACKAGE</v13:Level>
                    <v13:Description>Additional handling surcharge - dimension</v13:Description>
                    <v13:Amount>
                        <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                        <v13:Amount>9.0</v13:Amount>
                    </v13:Amount>
                </v13:Surcharges>
                <v13:Surcharges>
                    <v13:SurchargeType>FUEL</v13:SurchargeType>
                    <v13:Level>PACKAGE</v13:Level>
                    <v13:Description>FedEx Ground Fuel</v13:Description>
                    <v13:Amount>
                        <v13:Currency>USD</v13:Currency>
                        <v13:Amount>0.48</v13:Amount>
                    </v13:Amount>
                </v13:Surcharges>
            </v13:PackageRateDetails>
        </v13:PackageRating>

        <v13:SignatureOption>SERVICE_DEFAULT</v13:SignatureOption>
    </v13:CompletedPackageDetails>
</v13:CompletedShipmentDetail>
```

Below is the response i am getting currently in case of THIRD_PARTY Payment method.(Missing the above shown rate details)

```
<v13:CompletedShipmentDetail>
<v13:UsDomestic>true</v13:UsDomestic>
<v13:CarrierCode>FDXG</v13:CarrierCode>
<v13:PackagingDescription>YOUR_PACKAGING</v13:PackagingDescription>
<v13:OperationalDetail>
    <v13:OriginLocationNumber>928</v13:OriginLocationNumber>
    <v13:DestinationLocationNumber>952</v13:DestinationLocationNumber>
    <v13:TransitTime>TWO_DAYS</v13:TransitTime>
    <v13:IneligibleForMoneyBackGuarantee>false</v13:IneligibleForMoneyBackGuarantee>
    <v13:DeliveryEligibilities>SATURDAY_DELIVERY</v13:DeliveryEligibilities>
    <v13:ServiceCode>92</v13:ServiceCode>
</v13:OperationalDetail>
<v13:CompletedPackageDetails>
    <v13:SequenceNumber>1</v13:SequenceNumber>
    <v13:TrackingIds>
        <v13:TrackingIdType>FEDEX</v13:TrackingIdType>
        <v13:TrackingNumber>TRACKING_NUMBER</v13:TrackingNumber>
    </v13:TrackingIds>
    <v13:GroupNumber>0</v13:GroupNumber>
    <v13:OversizeClass>OVERSIZE_2</v13:OversizeClass>
    <v13:OperationalDetail>
        <v13:OperationalInstructions>
            <v13:Number>2</v13:Number>
            <v13:Content>TRK#</v13:Content>
        </v13:OperationalInstructions>
        <v13:OperationalInstructions>
            <v13:Number>7</v13:Number>
            <v13:Content>9622041730008000297100794662859700</v13:Content>
        </v13:OperationalInstructions>
        <v13:OperationalInstructions>
            <v13:Number>8</v13:Number>
            <v13:Content>539J2/3F56/31D0</v13:Content>
        </v13:OperationalInstructions>
        <v13:OperationalInstructions>
            <v13:Number>10</v13:Number>
            <v13:Content>7946 6285 9700</v13:Content>
        </v13:OperationalInstructions>
        <v13:OperationalInstructions>
            <v13:Number>15</v13:Number>
            <v13:Content>95206</v13:Content>
        </v13:OperationalInstructions>
        <v13:OperationalInstructions>
            <v13:Number>18</v13:Number>
            <v13:Content>9622 0417 3 (000 800 0297) 1 00 7946 6285 9700</v13:Content>
        </v13:OperationalInstructions>
        <v13:Barcodes>
            <v13:BinaryBarcodes>
                <v13:Type>COMMON_2D</v13:Type>
                <v13:Value>REMOVED_BARCODE_DATA</v13:Value>
            </v13:BinaryBarcodes>
            <v13:StringBarcodes>
                <v13:Type>FEDEX_1D</v13:Type>
                <v13:Value>REMOVED_BARCODE_DATA</v13:Value>
            </v13:StringBarcodes>
        </v13:Barcodes>
        <v13:GroundServiceCode>417</v13:GroundServiceCode>
    </v13:OperationalDetail>
    <v13:Label>
        <v13:Type>OUTBOUND_LABEL</v13:Type>
        <v13:ShippingDocumentDisposition>RETURNED</v13:ShippingDocumentDisposition>
        <v13:ImageType>PNG</v13:ImageType>
        <v13:Resolution>200</v13:Resolution>
        <v13:CopiesToPrint>1</v13:CopiesToPrint>
        <v13:Parts>
            <v13:DocumentPartSequenceNumber>1</v13:DocumentPartSequenceNumber>
            <v13:Image>REMOVED_IMAGE_DATA</v13:Image>
        </v13:Parts>
    </v13:Label>
    <v13:SignatureOption>SERVICE_DEFAULT</v13:SignatureOption>
</v13:CompletedPackageDetails>
```

Do i need to send some flag in request to receive the rate details for THIRD_PARTY Payment? Or will FEDEX not send the details for shipment rate in THIRD_PARTY payment cases?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Received response from FEDEX support team as stated below.

"In answer to your question, RateDetails are not returned for either RECIPIENT or THIRD_PARTY billing. This is considered private customer information and will only be provided for the SENDER account. This is working as designed."

Hope it saves someone's time facing similar issue :).

Answer (score 0):

For me is not working. No matter what I submit for `<vs:RateRequestTypes></vs:RateRequestTypes>` (LIST, PREFERRED or NONE) I am always getting the error message "Unable to obtain courtesy rates". I wonder if this is not working because I am still using the testing environment...